# $_SESSION difficulties

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, session

I am creating a login script that stores the value of a variable called `$userid` to `$_SESSION["userid"]` then redirects the user back to the main page (a side question is how to send them back where they were?).

However, when I get back to that page, I am echoing the `session_id()` and the value of `$_SESSION["userid"]` and only the session id shows up.  It had occurred to me that maybe my redirect page needs to have  at the top, but if this were true, then the session_id I'm echoing would change each time I end up on the page that is echoing it.  Here is the script:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once("db_include.php5");
doDB();
//check for required fields from the form
if ((empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['email'])) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
header("Location: loginform.php5");
exit;
}   else if($_POST["username"] && $_POST["password"]){

    //create and issue the query
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM aromaMaster WHERE username='".$_POST["username"]."' AND password=PASSWORD('".$_POST["password"]."')";
    $sql_res =mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

    //get the number of rows in the result set; should be 1 if a match
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_res) != 0) {
      //if authorized, get the userid
      while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_res)) {
        $userid = $_info["id"];
      }
      //set session variables
      $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;

      mysqli_free_result($sql_res);
      //redirect to main page
      header("Location: loginredirect.php5");
      exit; }
    } else if($_POST["email"] && $_POST["password"]) {

          //create and issue the query
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM aromaMaster WHERE email='".$_POST["email"]."' AND password=PASSWORD('".$_POST["password"]."')";
    $sql_res =mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

    //get the number of rows in the result set; should be 1 if a match
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_res) != 0) {

      //if authorized, get the userid
      while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_res)) {
        $userid = $_info["id"];
      }
      //set session variables
      $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;

      mysqli_free_result($sql_res);

      //redirect to main page
      header("Location: loginredirect.php5");
      exit;}
      } else {
      //redirect back to login form
      header("Location: loginform.php5");
      exit;
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: It should be noted that what you're doing leaves you wide open to a SQL injection attack. That's not how you use mysqli. Bind your parameters instead of using string concatenation. See http://au.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php.

Comment: Hm, I will read up on that.  The thing is, when typing in fields on my forms, onkeyup, a script runs that sanitizes the input, allowing only 0-9a-zA-z _-.@ (depending on what the field is for, but that is the most liberal it gets).  So, without <>()-+"';:&|$, what can anyone possibly do?

Comment: That script runs on the client. It can be disabled or requests can be spoofed. Client validation is only a convenience. **Never rely on client validation. You must always check on the server.**

Comment: Ah, good point.  Okay, I will run the strings through another regex before I send it, then sanitize with mysqli_real_escape_string(), then when reading it I have to sanitize with htmlspecialchars, right?

Comment: htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities() if sending it back to the client. you can use mysql_real_escape_string() but that step is implicit in a bind_param() method call, which imho is a much better pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You're doing this:**

```
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_res)) {
    $userid = $_info["id"];
}
```

**Where you should do this:**

```
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_res)) {
    $userid = $info["id"];
}
```

Comment: Oh you made the same typo twice in your code by the way, so make sure you change it at both points!

Comment: aren't both those loops identical?

Comment: No, please note the change from $_info['id'] to $info['id']

Comment: My answer as far as debugging would eventually find this - but yeah, The session value is being set wrong, so the session value is echo'ing wrong.

Comment: Ha, I know there's two the same :)
They are identical, but one works if the user has entered their username and password, and the second if they've only entered their email address and password.  I could have worked that into once condition and then decided inside which query to make, but that way was just simpler.  Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `session_write_close()` to store the session data changes.

Side answer: you can use the `$SERVER["HTTP REFERER"]` to redirect back, if it was filled by the browser

Comment: thanks, I'll look into the referer thing.  I may as well ask, though, what you mean 'if it was filled by the browser'?

Comment: session_write_close() should be called for you

Comment: In some (most?) browsers you can tell the browser not to send a referer header. For example in firefox set network.http.sendRefererHeader value to 0 to disable sending referrers.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So, I would just use header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTPREFERER"].""); ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure:

```
   <?php
   session_start();
```

Is at the top of each page.

Additionally, you can test by commenting out your redirects and echo'ing the value you're setting with to make sure you're retrieving/storing the correct value to begin with.